# garage door opener not working

Tags: garage-door-opener

I think the 'buzzing' noise I've clumsily described is actually the sound of the door-opener's motor running constantly.

The door went smoothly up and down as usual when I parked the car in the garage on Friday.  Afterwards, all was well and the motor was quiet.  On Saturday morning, I walked into the garage through the back door and it sounded like the door-opener's motor was running.   This had occurred suddenly and mysteriously overnight.   The garage door wouldn't open and I had to disconnect the power to stop the motor noise.

I've been opening the garage door (a tilt type) manually for the last few days by pulling the release cord.  That works fine.  I don't leave the opener plugged in because of the constant motor noise but each morning, I re-connect the power to see if the opener has fixed itself.  No such luck.

A stuck control relay sounds plausible but so far it hasn't rebooted.  Is there something I could try to 'unstick' it?  Is it possible for a novice to fix or replace the relay?

Comment: Unplug it and let it cool down then plug it back in if it still buzzes you may have a stuck control relay but in plugging may reboot

Answer (score 1):

Unplug the Opener , Disengage the Garage Door and Track / Chain Mechanism. Try to move the door manually to make sure it is disengaged.

After the Unit has been unplugged for 30 minutes , plug the unit back in . DO NOT RE-ENGAGE the door and the track/chain, try to run the opener - if the Unit operates you know the door was jammed and bound. Diagnose what might be causing the door to be jammed -, check your rollers and door track, check to make sure your door moves smoothly and will reach max close and max open. Check to verify the down switch gets made when the door is in the down position.

**EDIT 12/4/2017**

My rephrasing of your observations:

1. Your release cord is pulled and you can open manually.
2. When the release cord is not pulled.

   A. You can not open it manually.
   B. You can not open it
   automatically.
3. The noise is constant unless you unplug it.

You do not have a sticking relay. If the relay was sticking - and the motor was connected via the gear or pulley to the track - your motor would overload because the current draw of a locked rotor would blow the fuse or circuit breaker of the opener.

The motor continually running - this means that either a pulley is loose from the motor shaft , or if you have a belt the teeth on the belt are all gone (something of this nature.)

So the Gear / Pulley that is mounted to the motor shaft is loose or broken, usually a set screw or two keeps it stuck to the shaft.

Comment: Thanks, Ken.  Please see my edited post for clarification (I hope!) of the problem.

Comment: @Bernard Yes that helps a lot - your answer is in my edit - long story short - the motor gear is loose on the motor shaft - motor is running but spinning inside the pulley/gear ..

Comment: Thanks again Ken - that was helpful.  I'll take a look at the mechanics and see if I can spot where the problem lies.

Comment: Hi Ken.  It appears that the drive shaft from the motor is not turning.  When I turn the shaft by hand (by turning the chopper wheel) all the cogs and wheels engage as they should to move the chain which opens and closes the door.  Is that consistent with your diagnosis that the motor gear is probably loose?

Comment: @Bernard - The motor is turning - just the drive connection is loose - I am not sure what kind of opener you have but if I had a make and model - could look up the diagram and probably tell you where to look on that diagram - of course you could probably find out very quickly by just looking at the shaft and the pulley/gear mounting.

Answer (score 1):

Typically on the motor shaft, there is a little plastic (nylon) worm gear that drives the main gear, which does everything else. That worm gear is held to the shaft by a set screw. That set screw may have loosened, or the nylon gear may have cracked and is allowing the motor shaft to spin without moving the worm gear.
[image: Typical chain drive door opener motor]